# Check Zip File content and extract

Tags: c#, extract, unzip, zip

Hi I want to extract a ZipFile that has various of text files. But i could be that de text files are in a folder. So what i want to do is: If an folder exists just exract normaly if not create a folder with name of ZipFile. The reason is i don't want to have a folder in a folder with the same name.

My Previous Code:

```
    foreach (string file in newZips) {

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        string dirName = newPath + "\\" + fileInfo.Name.Substring(0, fileInfo.Name.Length - 4);
        Console.WriteLine(dirName);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirName);
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(allZipsPath + "\\" + fileInfo.Name, dirName);
    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If the Zip File contains a folder with text files unzip normaly. if the Zip file contains No folder but just the text files unzip it and create a folder which is called like the zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

```
string path = @"C:\..\..\myFolder";
if(!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

Thats how you can check a path if it contains the Folder you expect. And if not it creates that Folder!

--- EDIT (if unknown zip-Name) ---

```
string myPathToZip = @"C:\..\..\folderName";
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(myPathToZip, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{ 
    //the current path of the zipFile (with the Name included)
    var path = new FileInfo(file.ToString());

    //The filename
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.ToString()).Replace(".zip", "");
}
```

Comment: is this possible for zipFile ?

Comment: of Course... string myZip = @"C:\...\...\myZip.zip"; is also possible. The Directory Class of C# is pretty powerful.

Comment: But what is if i don't know the folder name in the zipFile, because it can be diffrent ?

Comment: Sry that i need to ask again. i know how to load the zip files but the content of the zip file is importent for me. is a folder IN the Zipfile or not?
do unterstand what i mean?

Comment: You have to unzip it first... and then you can see if there is a Folder in the zipfile or not ... you can check this with the code upstairs.